# Batch Rollback best practice

Tags: database, api, transaction

Context:
We have 2 servers (internal and external) that have to hold identical data and remain in sync the entire time.  Our internal system is like a local cache and we allow read/writes to the data before saving.  Saving triggers a local save and a save to the external system.

Single atomic changes are easy, but we have to begin handling batches.  Batches can have 100s of changes, and so the problem:

In case a batch fails, what is the best way to handle the failure?  Are there an established best practices in keeping two servers in sync the all the time?

FYI : Our local system is postgres the external system is unknown but they have RestFul API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not want to store invalid data in the database. The best practice is to treat database as an audit log and as such it should only contain valid data and nothing else (how you do it, whether using event sourcing or basic CRUD, is up to you).

When processing a batch of data you need to decide whether you can do partial saves and still consider the data to be valid. If the answer is yes, do that. If the answer is no, what you are probably looking for is [unit of work](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/unitOfWork.html).

When using unit of work you consider a business operation (which may be something as simple as updating a user password or a really complex financial transaction) a single working unit. You wrap the whole business transaction in a database transaction and either process it completely or not at all. In your case a whole transaction may be processing the entire batch of 100s of changes on data, but it may as well just be processing a part of it. You alone need to decide what the unit of work actually is.

You haven't specified a language. If you are working in Java you can have a look at Java's [`@Transactional`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/transaction/Transactional.html). I am a PHP programmer and the language sadly does not offer such feature. So if I want to treat a large business operation as a single unit I am forced to whip out my own solution.